# Is there a simple way to make @Cacheable i18n aware?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, internationalization

We've recently implemented i18n in our web services and we're using `@Cacheable` annotation to cache the call results in Redis.

The cache doesn't work when we try to test the web services by sending various `Accept-Language` header values. However, **when we clear the cache**, the web service returns a correct response that corresponds to the `Accept-Language` value that we've sent.

Is there a simple way to make `@Cacheable` i18n aware?

Note that we've already thought of a solution which is to send the `Accept-Language` header value from the Controller to the Service methods that are being cached, but we're not sure if this is a good practice as it will make our code hard to read and maintain.

Comment: can't you change your code to separate the translating part and the caching part? Like caching a key and then calling your i18n translator